# 3sistem solve 3Ignored

Tags: equation-solving

***is it correct this code?***

```
s = Solve[{4 \[Pi] (m/3 + n/4 + o/6) == 
    100.738, (4 \[Pi])/6 (m/5 + n/6 + o/8) == 
    3.9026, (4 \[Pi])/120 (m/7 + n/8 + o/10) == 0.0360176}, {m, n, o}]
```

***The answer that gives me is unreasonable***
***Hope someone guides me***